# stuck in GRUB RESCUE : insmod normal is unknown (solved)

Tags: grubrescue

**ISSUE :**

I tried to install Linux Lite by erasing a Kubuntu19 I had on a 2009 asus laptop. I must have messed it up obviously and now I am stuck in grub rescue. 
Here are some more infos on what is happening :

```
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1)

grub rescue> set
cmdpath=(hd0)
prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
root=hd0,msods1
```

**WHAT I TRIED :**

I read from several forums to first try to find the partition that holds root. As I have only one + the partition on my flash drive for my installation of Linux Lite I figured it was (hd0). However it is empty (? : not sure what it means though) :

```
grub rescue> ls (hd0)/
error: unknown filesystem.

grub rescue> ls (hd0)
(hd0): Filesystem is unknown.
```

later I tried (without altering anything else) :

```
grub rescue> insmod normal
error: unknown filesystem

grub rescue> normal
Unknown command 'normal'.
```

I found it a bit strange so I wanted to see which commands where there :

```
grub rescue> ismod
Unknown command 'ismod'.
```

After that I tried changing the sets to the (hd0) partition :

```
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0)/boot/grub
grub rescue> set root=hd0 
grub rescue> set
cmdpath=(hd0)
prefix=(hd0)/boot/grub
root=(hd0)
```

But same issue with insmod normal...

**SOLUTION**

[Boot-Repair](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/boot-repair) was my one and only savior ! (I had to reinstall everything afterwards tho)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Linux Lite isn't part of Ubuntu. You can ask your question in the Linux Lite forum or on the Unix Stack Exchange https://unix.stackexchange.com